# Golang - error `cannot find package`

Tags: github, go

After using go get to get on github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 I get an error stating "golang.org/x/net/context".

I'm not sure as to where to look to resolve this issue

Comment: I've met this before. try `go get golang.org/x/net/context` first, see what this command outputs.

Comment: I've faced this issue before and reinstalling/upgrading fixed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you download the source code for the `context` package?

One common way to do that is to use the bundled tool `go get` by doing:

```
go get golang.org/x/net/context
```

This should import the source code for the `context` package into your Go workspace which is defined by the `GOPATH` environment variable. (In your case the package's code will be downloaded to `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/net/context`.)

Alternatively you can do a `go get` on the parent package to include all of its dependencies automatically without needing to find and download them one at a time. For example:

```
go get github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to you `github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` folder.
And run `go get ./...` to install all dependencies into your project folder.

As your project's dependencies should come from `github` It will install all the dependencies into `$GOPATH/src/github.com`